# Checking code before I deploy it

Tags: trigger, custom-object, deployment, file-processing

Just making sure that my code looks correct before I shoot myself in the foot. I just need this trigger to generate a custom object with an attachment for every ContentVersion there is that's a jpg image and is from the current user's content library. There's over 4,000 files in the library, and I just want to know that this will do everything as it should. Can anyone help?

### EDITS:

After more digging, it turns out there was a trigger made already for adding `ProductRegistration__c` objects. Following the same format of how that trigger was coded, as well as adding code based off the suggestions provided here, these are the changes I've made. Additionally, I took a look at the file size for each upload. Each file is roughly less than 100 KB in size each.

```
trigger ContentVersionToAttachment on ContentVersion(after insert, after update) {
    ProductRegistration.addAttachments(Trigger.new);
}
```

Apex class method for adding attachments to product registrations:

```
// ...
public static void addAttachments(List<ContentVersion> contentList) {
    List<ProductRegistration__c> productRegistrationsToInsert = new List<ProductRegistration__c>();
    List<Attachment> attachmentsToInsert = new List<Attachment>();

    for(ContentVersion c : Trigger.new) {
        ProductRegistration__c r = new ProductRegistration__c(
            RegistrationId__c = Decimal.valueOf(c.Id),
            Contact__c = null, Product__c = null, PurchasedDate__c = null,
            ManufactureDate__c = null, RegisteredDate__c = dateToday,
            Registration_Method__c = 'TAB Services');
        productRegistrationsToInsert.add(r);
        Blob image = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(String.valueOf(c.VersionData));
        Attachment a = new Attachment(
            Id = c.ContentDocumentId, ParentId = r.Id,
            Name = c.PathOnClient, Body = image,
            ContentType = c.FileType, Description = c.Description,
            IsPrivate = false);
        attachmentsToInsert.add(a);
    }
    insert productRegistrationsToInsert;
    insert attachmentsToInsert;
}
```

Comment: You have 2 DML operations for every record in the trigger context...this will most certainly not work if you plan on inserting all 4000 at once

Comment: :< shoot...are those not allowed? I need it to generate mostly empty ProductRegistration__c records, aside from the Attachment to be uploaded with each record, for every ContentVersion it finds. Is there a way to fix it, or do I need something different? I didn't really want it all at once, it can process it over time if needed.

Comment: Also,  if trigger.new contained 2 records created by the current user then saveAttachments will create 4 product registrations and 4 attachments.  If this is not your intent then change saveAttachments() to `saveAttachments(ContentVersion cv1)` and remove the for loop within the body of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments above...you're limited to 150 DML statements per execution context, so instead of inserting the records one at a time, accumulate them in a collection and insert that (which helpfully only counts as one DML statement).

The following illustrates the idea, you'll have to reorganize your method a little bit to make it work, but this brings several thousand DML statements down to two:

```
// collections to hold records to insert
List<ProductRegistration__c> productRegistrationsToInsert = new List<ProductRegistration__c>();
List<Attachment> attachmentsToInsert = new List<Attachment>();

for(ContentVersion c : cvl) {

   r = new ProductRegistration__c(
      RegistrationId__c = Decimal.valueOf(c.Id),
      Contact__c = null, Product__c = null, PurchasedDate__c = null,
      ManufactureDate__c = null, RegisteredDate__c = Date.today(),
      Registration_Method__c = 'TAB Services'
   );

   productRegistrationsToInsert.add(r);

   Blob image = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(String.valueOf(c.VersionData));

   a = new Attachment(
      Id = c.ContentDocumentId, ParentId = r.Id,
      Name = c.PathOnClient, Body = image,
      ContentType = c.FileType, Description = c.Description,
      IsPrivate = false
   );

   attachmentsToInsert.add(a);
}

insert productRegistrationsToInsert;
insert attachmentsToInsert;
```

Comment: there could be heap issues if `image` is large and contentversions are uploaded in bulk

Comment: that's a really good point as well. batch apex?

Comment: I'll have to try this out on the dev org later, and I'll give a college try to what ever else I can think of. If I get an answer to this, I'll post it later on :) thank you

Comment: Now that I think of it - even on a single ContentVersion, if image is large (like a RAW photofile), the heap may blow up as ContentVersion uploads can be larger (2GB in some use cases) than attachment uploads (25 MB) - see https://na2.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf (File-related Limits)

Comment: I've been trying to rewrite my code to make it use batch apex, and I thought of something to ask. Can the class be coded to limit how many objects it processes at a given time? If so, I could stagger the number of ContentVersion objects being converted to Attachments.